# MSI Installer: Adding a non default action to a file extension

Tags: contextmenu, file-extension, file-association, installshield-le, orca

I'm working on an MSI Installer project. I would like to add an action to an existing file extension that will be available only from the context menu, while keeping the current default action as is. For instance - add an "Edit with my program" action to a .jpeg, while double-clicking a .jpeg will still open it with the default viewer and not with my application.

When I create a file extension association in InstallShield 2013 Limited Edition for Visual Studio, it makes my action the default one. I don't see a way to change that.

I've also tried to edit with Orca the Sequence of the command in the [Verb Table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372487%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to 9999, to no avail.

Can anybody please tell me how to do that with InstallShield 2013 Limited Edition or with Orca?